# Calculating magnitude for unit tangent vector

Tags: vectors, radicals, parametric, arc-length

The image I'm including IS from a mymathlab assignment, but it's a practice assignment, so it's not homework.  I just need to understand how it was done.

[image: Steps]

I understand the concept of calculating v(t).  You take the derivative of each individual component and them put them back in ijk form.  That makes sense to me, and I got the first step correct.  The next part is where I get confused.

On the very next step, they show v as equal to (18t^2)i - (2t^2)j + (3t^2)k.

This confuses me because in the very previous step we had established that v was actually equal to (18t^2)i + (-6t^2)j + (9t^2)k.  Why in the next step are the j and k components suddenly different?

Finally, I don't know how to calculate the magnitude from even those components.  I would set it up as sqrt((18t^2)i - (2t^2)j + (3t^2)k) but I don't know how to calculate that square root.

Please help

Comment: Did you miss the differential? To get the tangent, you take the derivative of each component with respect to the curve parameter: $\frac{d (6t^3)}{d t} = 3 \cdot 6 t^{3-1} = 18 t^2$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally, I don't know how to calculate the magnitude from even those components. I

You can pull the $t^2$ factor
$$
v = 18 t^2 i - 2t^2 j + 3t^2 k = t^2 (18i-2j+3k)
$$
and then using $\lVert \alpha x \rVert = \lvert \alpha \rvert \lVert x \rVert$:
$$
\lVert v \rVert 
= \lvert t^2 \rvert \lVert 18i-2j+3k \rVert
= t^2 \sqrt{18^2 + 2^2 + 3^2} 
= t^2 \sqrt{337} 
= t^2 \cdot 18.35\dotsb
$$
If we try the other version:
$$
\lVert v \rVert 
= \lvert t^2 \rvert \lVert 18i-6j+9k \rVert
= t^2 \sqrt{18^2 + 6^2 + 9^2} 
= t^2 \sqrt{441} 
= t^2 \cdot 21
$$
This fits better. So it seems to be some error which slipped in.

Comment: That last explanation makes a lot more sense.  Thanks!